# $|f(z)|^{2}\leq \frac{1}{\pi r^{2}}\iint_{D(z,r)} |f(\theta)|^{2}dm(\theta)$ for $f \in H(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $\Omega $ be a domain ,$\overline{D(z,r)} \subset \Omega $, $f$ holomorphic in $\Omega$.

a) Show that  $$|f(z)|^{2}\leq \frac{1}{\pi r^{2}}\iint_{D(z,r)} |f(\theta)|^{2}dm(\theta)$$ where $dm$ denotes the lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{C} \equiv \mathbb{R^{2}} $.

b) For $M\geq 0 $ let $$  F = \left\{f \in H(\Omega)| \ \iint_{\Omega} |f(\theta)|^{2}dm(\theta) \leq M\right\}$$. Then show that $F$ is normal.

Any hint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $g(z)=f^2(z)$ is also analytic, [Mean Value Theorem for Analytic Functions](http://planetmath.org/proofofgaussmeanvaluetheorem) provides that
$$
f^2(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f^2(z+\varrho\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta})d\vartheta,
$$
which implies using polar coordinates 
\begin{align}
\int_{D_r(z)} f^2(x+iy)\,dx\,dy&=
\int_0^r\int_0^{2\pi}f^2\big(z+\varrho\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta}\big)\,d\vartheta\,\varrho\,d\varrho=\int_0^r 2\pi\, f^2(z)\,\varrho\,d\varrho=\pi r^2 f(z),
\end{align}
and thus
$$
\int_{D_r(z)} |f(x+iy)|^2\,dx\,dy \ge \left| \int_{D_r(z)} f^2(x+iy)\,dx\,dy
\right|
=\pi r^2\,|f^2(z)|.
$$

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the subharmonicity argument, you can also explicitly (well, sort of) evaluate

$$\int_{D(z;r)} \lvert f(\theta)\rvert^2\,dm(\theta)$$

using the Taylor expansion of $f$ about $z$,

$$f(\theta) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(\theta-z)^n \Rightarrow \lvert f(\theta)\rvert^2 = \sum_{m,n=0}^\infty a_n\overline{a_m}(\theta-z)^n\overline{(\theta-z)^m}.$$

Write $\theta = z + \rho e^{i\varphi}$ and integrate in polar coordinates to get a nice expression for the integral. Use that $f(z) = a_0$.

For b), the condition implies that

$$\int_{D(z;r)} \lvert f(\theta)\rvert^2 \,dm(\theta) \leqslant M$$

for all $z \in \Omega$ and $r > 0$ such that $D(z;r) \subset \Omega$.

Then use a) to obtain the premises of the little Montel theorem.

Comment: Okay, then a) tells us that $F$ is locally bounded.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for a)**

1. WLOG assume $z=0$, by subharmonicity we have 
   $$|f(0)|^2\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(\rho e^{i\phi})|^2d\phi$$
2. Now, $d\phi$ is **not** the area measure - what is missing?

Comment: Note that this argument works fine for any positive exponent, not just 2.

Comment: (The area measure in polar coordinates is $(\rho,\phi)\mapsto \rho d\rho d\phi$)